# how to create a flexible content area with repeating background image with fixed image transitions/caps at top and bottom?

Tags: css, background-image

I have a webpage that I want to style up to look like an open book, having a crease/shadow down the middle.  The height of the page is not fixed but flexible and grows with the content.  The body element has a background image of the paper texture without any shadows.

For the shadow my designer has given me 3 semi-transparent pngs:

1. crease_top.png which contains the transition of the top of the book.
2. crease_center.png which is a repeatable middle section of the shadow, that can grow with the content of the page.
3. crease_bottom.png which contains the bottom section of the shadow.

So here is my problem: I can't use absolute positioned top and bottom on top of a 100% height shadow because transparent images can't cover up properly.  I could position all 3 divs on top of each other in a normal flow, but I don't know how to set the height of the middle div.  I need something like height: 100% minus height of top and bottom pngs, to get the repeating area.  I can't use padding because padding pushes the center div taller and doesn't restrict the background image.

Here is what I have so far, but I am willing to change it if need be for a better implementation:

```
<div id="sketchbook_post">

     <div id="crease_wrap">
       <div id="crease_top">
       </div>
       <div id="crease_center">
       </div>
       <div id="crease_bottom">
       </div>
     </div>

</div>


#crease_wrap {
      position:absolute;
      top:0;
      left:50px;
      height:100%;
      width:50px;
    }
#crease_top {
      height:105px;
      width:53px;
      background-image: url(<%= asset_path 'page-crease_top.png' %>);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;

    }
#crease_center {
      width:53px;
      padding-top:105px;
      padding-bottom:176px;
      background-image: url(<%= asset_path 'page-crease_center.png' %>);
      background-repeat: repeat-y;

    }

#crease_bottom {
      height:167px;
      width:53px;
      background-image: url(<%= asset_path 'page-crease_bottom.png' %>);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;

    }
```

What do you suggest as some approaches to solve this kind of problem?

Comment: Could you show some HTML/CSS how these divs are setup and styled?

Comment: Yes, I have updated my question to include what I have so far.

Comment: So is your problem that the top/bottom images will overlap the middle image if the container is 100%?

Comment: yes, overlapping images will not work because they are partially transparent.  they images simulate shadows.  i'm looking for a css only solution, without js or tables... if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a `<table>` would be helpful in this case...

```
    <div id="sketchbook_post">
    <table id="crease_wrap" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td id="crease_top">
                <div>&nbsp;</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="crease_center">
                <div style="height:100%;">&nbsp;</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
           <tr>
            <td id="crease_bottom">
                <div>&nbsp;</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
     </table>
</div>

    #crease_wrap {
      position:absolute;
      top:0;
      left:50px;
      height:100%;
      width:50px;
    }
#crease_top {
      height:105px;
      width:53px;
      background-image: url(<%= asset_path 'page-crease_top.png' %>);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;

    }
#crease_center {
      width:53px;
      height:100%;
      background-image: url(<%= asset_path 'page-crease_center.png' %>);
      background-repeat: repeat-y;

    }

#crease_bottom {
      height:167px;
      width:53px;
      background-image: url(<%= asset_path 'page-crease_bottom.png' %>);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;

    }
```

Comment: I updated it by adding a height:100% to the center div.  Also you may want to add a "vertical-align:top;" to your center table cell.

Answer (score 0):

Because your top/bottom images are fixed height, I would suggest using javascript to adjust the height of the the middle content area as the page size changes. If you were using prototypejs for example, you could so something like...

```
window.onresize = function() {
    $('crease_center').setStyle({ height: (document.viewport.getHeight() - 272) + 'px' });
}
```

Where 272 represents the combined height of the top/bottom elements.